# How to create a copy of a PDF file in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I'm reading a PDF file for writing a string on it like this :

```
public ActionResult Index(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{


    byte[] pdfbytes = null;
    BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream);
    pdfbytes = rdr.ReadBytes((int)file.ContentLength);
    PdfReader myReader = new PdfReader(pdfbytes);
```

and I'm trying to pass a new file to `FileStream` like this :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
```

But I don't know how to pass the copied new file to `fs` object. Can you help me with that? Thanks.

Comment: Build a memory stream with pdfbytes and then use the memorystream WriteTo method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to updated byte array pass it to `File.WriteAllBytes`. Or you might have an instance of PdfDocument or PdfWriter which usually allow saving the document to file on disk too. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Here is example which is reading existing pdf file, copying it to new one and adding new string line:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string originalFile = "c:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\receipt mod 3.pdf";
            string copyOfOriginal = "c:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\newFile.pdf";

            using (var reader = new PdfReader(originalFile))
            {
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(copyOfOriginal, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                {
                    var document = new Document(reader.GetPageSizeWithRotation(1));
                    var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fileStream);

                    document.Open();

                    for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        document.NewPage();

                        var baseFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.HELVETICA_BOLD, BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                        var importedPage = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);

                        var contentByte = writer.DirectContent;
                        contentByte.BeginText();
                        contentByte.SetFontAndSize(baseFont, 12);

                        var LineString = "Hello World!";

                        contentByte.ShowTextAligned(10,LineString,50,50,0);

                        contentByte.EndText();
                        contentByte.AddTemplate(importedPage, 0, 0);
                    }

                    document.Close();
                    writer.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
This program copies all pdf files from one location to another.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
      {

    string sourceDirectory = @"D:\project training\source";

            string targetDirectory = @"D:\project training\destiny";

            Copy(sourceDirectory, targetDirectory);
        }
        public static void Copy(string sourceDirectory, string targetDirectory)
        {
            DirectoryInfo diSource = new DirectoryInfo(sourceDirectory);
            DirectoryInfo diTarget = new DirectoryInfo(targetDirectory);

            CopyAll(diSource, diTarget);
        }
        public static void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
        {



            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
            foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
            {
                if (fi.Extension.Equals(".pdf"))
                {
                    fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.FullName, fi.Name), true);
                }
            }


            foreach (DirectoryInfo diSourceSubDir in source.GetDirectories())
            {
                DirectoryInfo nextTargetSubDir =
                    target.CreateSubdirectory(diSourceSubDir.Name);
                CopyAll(diSourceSubDir, nextTargetSubDir);
            }
        }
```

Comment: oh i am sorry just now I understood your question. you need to make a copy to edit? really sorry . The code I entered only copy pdf files